# Datadog standalone python log management

Tags: python, logging, datadog

I am struggling to get my log management set up for datadog with a standalone python app.
My goal is to get the sample json to be "read" by datadog, and what I see is that my python integration seems to be connected to datadog but the log files are not getting through.

My python code to be run is shown below, not actual code but it is a similar model. The logs are the metrics to be recorded for datadog. I read up on datadog's documentation and all and alot of the docs seem to incorporate other apps like docker, which is not my case here.

I have included ddtrace as that was what I read in the documentation, but it doesn't seem to work. I included it in my code for reference.

I appreciate any tips/guidance to point me in the right direction!

My python code

```
import logging
import json_log_formatter
from ddtrace import config, patch_all

config.env = "test"      # the environment the application is in
config.service = "test"  # name of your application
config.version = "0.1"  # version of your application
patch_all()

formatter = json_log_formatter.JSONFormatter()

json_handler = logging.FileHandler('sample.json')
json_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(json_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


try:
    for i in range(len(10)):
        try:
            # check if file exists
            if os.path.isfile('xx') == True:
        logger.info("all ok")
            else:
                logger.info("File doesn't exist", extra={'file': 'xx', 'level' : 'info'})
        except:
            logger.warning("Error handling file of xx", extra={'file': 'xx', 'level' : 'warning'})
except:
  logger.debug("Issue before even checking file exists", extra={'level' : 'debug'})
```

I'm not sure if I got the datadog settings right, so I'm including it here

My python.d/conf.yml

```
init_config:
 
instances:
#Log section
logs:
 
    # - type : file (mandatory) type of log input source (tcp / udp / file)
    #   port / path : (mandatory) Set port if type is tcp or udp. Set path if type is file
    #   service : (mandatory) name of the service owning the log
    #   source : (mandatory) attribute that defines which integration is sending the log
    #   sourcecategory : (optional) Multiple value attribute. Can be used to refine the source attribute
    #   tags: (optional) add tags to each log collected
 
  - type: file
    path: /C:/xx/xx/xx/sample.json
    service: myapplication
    source: python
    sourcecategory: sourcecode
```

My datadog.yaml file - sorry it's really long but I included the parts where I think it's important! The rest that are not included are commented out.

```
#########################
## Basic Configuration ##
#########################

api_key: key


site: datadoghq.com


##################################
## Log collection Configuration ##
##################################

## @param logs_enabled - boolean - optional - default: false
## @env DD_LOGS_ENABLED - boolean - optional - default: false
## Enable Datadog Agent log collection by setting logs_enabled to true.
#
logs_enabled: true

## @param logs_config - custom object - optional
## Enter specific configurations for your Log collection.
## Uncomment this parameter and the one below to enable them.
## See https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/
logs_config:

  ## @param container_collect_all - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## @env DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Enable container log collection for all the containers (see ac_exclude to filter out containers)
  container_collect_all: false

  ## @param logs_dd_url - string - optional
  ## @env DD_LOGS_CONFIG_DD_URL - string - optional
  ## Define the endpoint and port to hit when using a proxy for logs. The logs are forwarded in TCP
  ## therefore the proxy must be able to handle TCP connections.
  logs_dd_url: <ENDPOINT>:<PORT>

  ## @param logs_no_ssl - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## @env DD_LOGS_CONFIG_LOGS_NO_SSL - optional - default: false
  ## Disable the SSL encryption. This parameter should only be used when logs are
  ## forwarded locally to a proxy. It is highly recommended to then handle the SSL encryption
  ## on the proxy side.
  logs_no_ssl: false

  ## @param processing_rules - list of custom objects - optional
  ## @env DD_LOGS_CONFIG_PROCESSING_RULES - list of custom objects - optional
  ## Global processing rules that are applied to all logs. The available rules are
  ## "exclude_at_match", "include_at_match" and "mask_sequences". More information in Datadog documentation:
  ## https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/#global-processing-rules
  processing_rules:
    - type: <RULE_TYPE>
      name: <RULE_NAME>
      pattern: <RULE_PATTERN>

  ## @param use_http - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## @env DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## By default, logs are sent through TCP, use this parameter
  ## to send logs in HTTPS batches to port 443
  use_http: true

  ## @param use_tcp - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## @env DD_USE_TCP - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## By default, logs are sent through HTTP if possible, use this parameter
  ## to send logs in TCP
  use_tcp: true

  ## @param use_compression - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## @env DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_COMPRESSION - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## This parameter is available when sending logs with HTTPS. If enabled, the Agent
  ## compresses logs before sending them.
  use_compression: true

  ## @param compression_level - integer - optional - default: 6
  ## @env DD_LOGS_CONFIG_COMPRESSION_LEVEL - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## The compression_level parameter accepts values from 0 (no compression)
  ## to 9 (maximum compression but higher resource usage).
  compression_level: 6

  ## @param batch_wait - integer - optional - default: 5
  ## @env DD_LOGS_CONFIG_BATCH_WAIT - integer - optional - default: 5
  ## The maximum time the Datadog Agent waits to fill each batch of logs before sending.
  batch_wait: 5




###########################
## Logging Configuration ##
###########################

## @param log_level - string - optional - default: info
## @env DD_LOG_LEVEL - string - optional - default: info
## Minimum log level of the Datadog Agent.
## Valid log levels are: trace, debug, info, warn, error, critical, and off.
## Note: When using the 'off' log level, quotes are mandatory.
#
# log_level: 'info'

## @param log_file - string - optional
## @env DD_LOG_FILE - string - optional
## Path of the log file for the Datadog Agent.
## See https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/guide/agent-log-files/
#
# log_file: <AGENT_LOG_FILE_PATH>

## @param log_format_json - boolean - optional - default: false
## @env DD_LOG_FORMAT_JSON - boolean - optional - default: false
## Set to 'true' to output Agent logs in JSON format.
#
# log_format_json: false

## @param log_to_console - boolean - optional - default: true
## @env DD_LOG_TO_CONSOLE - boolean - optional - default: true
## Set to 'false' to disable Agent logging to stdout.
#
# log_to_console: true

## @param disable_file_logging - boolean - optional - default: false
## @env DD_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING - boolean - optional - default: false
## Set to 'true' to disable logging to the log file.
#
# disable_file_logging: false

## @param log_file_max_size - custom - optional - default: 10MB
## @env DD_LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE - custom - optional - default: 10MB
## Maximum size of one log file. Use either a size (e.g. 10MB) or
## provide value in bytes: 10485760
#
# log_file_max_size: 10MB

## @param log_file_max_rolls - integer - optional - default: 1
## @env DD_LOG_FILE_MAX_ROLLS - integer - optional - default: 1
## Maximum amount of "old" log files to keep.
## Set to 0 to not limit the number of files to create.
#
# log_file_max_rolls: 1

## @param log_to_syslog - boolean - optional - default: false
## @env DD_LOG_TO_SYSLOG - boolean - optional - default: false
## Set to 'true' to enable logging to syslog.
## Note: Even if this option is set to 'false', the service launcher of your environment
## may redirect the Agent process' stdout/stderr to syslog. In that case, if you wish
## to disable logging to syslog entirely, set 'log_to_console' to 'false' as well.
#
# log_to_syslog: false

## @param syslog_uri - string - optional
## @env DD_SYSLOG_URI - string - optional
## Define a custom remote syslog uri if needed. If 'syslog_uri' is left undefined/empty,
## a local domain socket connection is attempted.
#
# syslog_uri: <SYSLOG_URI>

## @param syslog_rfc - boolean - optional - default: false
## @env DD_SYSLOG_RFC - boolean - optional - default: false
## Set to 'true' to output in an RFC 5424-compliant format for Agent logs.
#
# syslog_rfc: false

## @param syslog_pem - string - optional
## @env DD_SYSLOG_PEM - string - optional
## If TLS enabled, you must specify a path to a PEM certificate here.
#
# syslog_pem: <PEM_CERTIFICATE_PATH>

## @param syslog_key - string - optional
## @env DD_SYSLOG_KEY - string - optional
## If TLS enabled, you must specify a path to a private key here.
#
# syslog_key: <PEM_KEY_PATH>

## @param syslog_tls_verify - boolean - optional - default: true
## @env DD_SYSLOG_TLS_VERIFY - boolean - optional - default: true
## If TLS enabled, you may enforce TLS verification here.
#
# syslog_tls_verify: true

## @param log_format_rfc3339 - boolean - optional - default false
## @env DD_LOG_FORMAT_RFC3339 - boolean - optional - default false
## If enabled the Agent will log using the RFC3339 format for the log time.
#
# log_format_rfc3339: false

## @param log_all_goroutines_when_unhealthy - boolean - optional - default false
## @env DD_LOG_ALL_GOROUTINES_WHEN_UNHEALTHY - boolean - optional - default false
## If enabled, when the health probe of an internal component fails, the stack traces
## of all the goroutines are logged.
#
# log_all_goroutines_when_unhealthy: false
```

Comment: ddtrace is for application performance monitoring (e.g. how long is this function call taking?) rather than collecting logs. Are you also running the Datadog agent? https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/

Comment: Yup, I am running the Datadog agent. I thought it was a requirement for the APM to be set up first before collecting logs (since the datadog log documentation kept referring to APM), but I'm not too sure

Comment: Ok, did some troubleshooting and I realised the log file can't be read by Datadog (does not exist for my agent). I am guessing it's a permissions error, and the documentation said to fix with chmod but I'm on windows, so I'm working on that now!